# yesod-ghc-wrapper issue when running 'yesod devel' for first time

Tags: haskell, ubuntu-12.04, yesod

I have ghc in my path, have set up yesod init and cabal built it.

Now, when I 'yesod devel' I get :

> cabal: Cannot find the program 'ghc' at 'yesod-ghc-wrapper' or on the path

ghc **IS** on the path!

thanks

Comment: I can't say I've ever seen that error message before. If no one responds on SO, it may be worth sending a question to the mailing list.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen that if the path to the yesod bin directory under cabal is not in my PATH.

Try changing your PATH to include the yesod directory and see if it goes away.

For example, in my .bash_profile I have:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/username/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.4.2/lib/yesod-bin-1.2.2/bin/
```